# Numpy vectorization with calculation depending on previous value(s)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Is there is a vectorized way to change all concurrent 1s that are within `offset` of the first `1` into `0`s (transform `A` into `B`)?  I'm currently trying to do this on a numpy array with over 1 million items where speed is critical.

The `1`s represent a signal trigger and the `0`s represent no trigger. For example: Given an offset of 5, whenever there is a `1`, the following 5 items must be `0` (to remove signal concurrency).

**Example 1:**

```
offset = 3
A = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
B = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

**Example 2:**

```
offset = 2
A = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
B = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand exactly how you're going from A to B

Comment: Just updated the question. Lmk if that clears things up.

Comment: The position of the first `1` after a `0` is `np.argwhere(np.diff(np.pad(A,1)) == 1).squeeze()`.  But that doesn't really help for the question at hand, as you also want to count the `1`s after newly created `0`s.

Comment: "vectorization" is easiest when the action is 'parallel' - same action on all elements regardless of order.  `numpy` methods don't implement a sequential actions except for limited cases like `cumsum` and similar `ufunc.accumulate`.  It's not that sequential actions can't be coded, but that it's harder to create building blocks that can be applied one after the other.  At some point you may need to resort to a compiling tool like `numba`.

Comment: I'd start with a list based solution.  With a better understanding of the task, you might see pattern(s) that allow you express in a 'multidimensional' way.  But with sequences that differ in length and spacing that may be difficult.  It may be easier to speed up with `numba` than trying to squeeze out some sort of whole-array `numpy` solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I managed to fully vectorize this by using JohanC's code to return a np array of indicies, ```indicies```, then creating an array of ```0```s of shape ```A.shape```, and then finally setting all index positions that match ```indices``` to ```1```. This solution works for all cases except for where there isn't a ```0``` separating 2 window periods.

Comment: @AllenChen does your problem solved? I did your explain solution but it has shortcomings and is not a complete solution e.g. what if you have `offset=2` and 3 or more times of repeated `1` like your above examples? Does it solve the problem truly?

Comment: @Ali_Sh unfortunately it is only a partial solution, however because speed is absolutely paramount, I am using it as a temporary fill-in so that I am able to continue moving forward for my project.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems that, the question is not just related to use NumPy and …, and the main objective is to speed up the code. Since, you are using the partial solution, mentioned by *JohanC*, (Which needs much more considerations for this question), I suggest the following methods:

```
def com_():
    n = 1
    for i in range(1, len(A)+1):
        if A[n-1] == 1:
            A[n:n+offset] = 0
            n += offset + 1
        else:
            n += 1
        if n > len(A):
            break


@nb.jit(forceobj=True)
def com_fast(): 
    B = A.tolist()
    n = 1
    while n < len(B):
        if B[n-1] == 1:
            for i in range(offset):
                if n+i < len(B):
                    B[n+i] = 0
            n += offset + 1
        else:
            n += 1
```

The first method is using A in the form of *NumPy array* and loops. The second one uses an input in the form of *list* and loops, and is accelerated by `numba` as it is mentioned by *hpaulj* in the comments.
Using the same inputs (`1,000,000 in length`) for the methods, and running on Google Colab TPU:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 153 ms per loop         # for com_()
1000 loops, best of 5: 10.2 ms per loop        # for com_fast()
```

Which, I think, will show acceptable performance times with that large data.
I think, this question could not be solved just by NumPy, or if so, It will be very difficult and need to think about it a lot (I have tried and I achieved good results, **but** finally needs to loops). My guess is that, using `numba` and libraries like that, could have similar results (in runtime) and, so, it does not need to use just NumPy.